# how to find a pandas dataframe index with a similar keyword?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am currently working on creating a database where the tables are made from specific columns from an excel workbook. The algorithm iterates in a directory and saves the worksheet as a pandas dataframe and from there I select the columns:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(file, 'sheet1')
```

From there I select the data I need with

```
def create_list(df1):
    i = 0
    list1 = [] 
    while isinstance(df1['foo-bar'][i], int):
        list1.append(df1['foo-bar'][i])
        i += 1
    return list1
```

The problem I'm facing is that sometimes the name of the column isn't 'foo-bar' but 'foo.bar'. Is there a way to select this column just if it contains 'foo' for example? Or an 'or' operator, that selects 'foo-bar' or 'foo.bar'?

I know that there should be a way with LIKE from sql, but I would prefer to do it with pandas.

Comment: are you iterating through the file? if so.. you should be doing i += 1 right?

Comment: Does `df.filter(like='foo')` work for you - that'll return a DF with columns containing that...

Comment: @GabrielM you're right, I forgot to put it on the code.

Comment: @JonClements you're right, this already helps a lot

Comment: it works perfectly with `df.filter(like = 'foo' and 'bar) `

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame.filter` this way... Since df1 is a dataframe:

```
    df1 = df1.filter(regex=("^foo.*"))
```

Comment: in case it would take all the columns whose name begins with foo

Comment: `regex=` uses `re.search`  - so to make sure the name *begins with* "foo" you need to *anchor* the regex, eg: `regex='^foo'`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

regex = re.compile("^foo.*")

columnsThatYouWant = []

for i in dataframe.columns:

    if bool(regex.match(i))):
        columnsThatYouWant.append(i)
```

Then you could use all the columns inside it.

This is called regex.

^foo.* means a string start with foo and ends with any char(".") with whatever length("*")

Comment: and how would it be to specify the char or string that it should end? in this case forcing it to start with 'foo' and end with 'bar'?

Comment: I found [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for regex, but there it shows "$" as the end